# Having trouble addressing with objects created at run-time

Tags: c#, browser, runtime, instances

I am quite new to programming and I was attempting to make a small browser in 
Win-forms.
I wanted to expand on the code I got from a tutorial which is used to create a new tab:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
public browsertab() {
    wb.SetBounds(0,0, helper.formWidth - 30, helper.formHeight - 30);
    wb.Url = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
    this.Controls.Add(wb);
}
```

Now this code works fine, except i can't find a way to address the browser in the currently open tab since the name doesn't exist on startup. **I want the searchbar to search in the currently open tab** but i can't seem to do it. **Can anyone help me with naming and accesing these instances of the browser?**

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: what do you mean with "address the browser"?

Comment: I meant change the URL/ website

Comment: Is 'this' the form or the tab? I think 'this' is the form.  It looks like you have only one WebBrowser and you are putting it on top of the tab so it looks like it is on the current tab.  You would need an array of WebBrowser (or an array of URL).  Then add each WebBrowser to each tab.

Comment: I don't know what the code does, the tutorial doesn't explain it. but it places a browser on every tab of a tablist. each one is unique, as in if i change one the others all stay the same and don't change

Comment: assuming you are working on the control, to which you added the Brwoser you could try something like this `WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser) this.Controls.SingleOrDefault(ctrl => ctrl is WebBrowser)`

Comment: Thanks, i will test it in a bit, what does it do exactly (sorry for asking, but i really can't tell).

Comment: if your control (presumably yout tab page) has exactly one sub control of type WebBrowser it will be returned by SingleOrDefault() or null if there is no WebBrowser control

Comment: I'm sorry, this is probably my fault, but it underlines SingleOrDeafault what i paste it into my project and i can't get it to work